# Full height, variable width images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this site for quite a while, but am still having trouble with a couple of things. Here's the layout:

- Top navigation bar: 68px tall, full-width, fixed to top.
- Bottom navigation bar: 42px tall, full-width, fixed to bottom.
- Content: full-height images with various widths, floated to the left.

Navigating the content is done by horizontal scrolling only. It's extremely important that the images fill the full height from the bottom of the top nav bar to the top of the bottom nav bar, and are not cropped or obscured in any way. It's also very important that resizing the browser window or rotating a mobile device doesn't break this layout. My current code works perfectly in Chrome and Safari (with one [caveat](http://micho.biz/mac-osx-lion-horizontal-scroll-event/)), but fails miserably in Firefox and Opera. I haven't tested in IE yet. Here's what I'm doing:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 68px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 42px;
  z-index: -10;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#content #frame {
  max-width: 80000px; /* (To ensure that there's enough horizontal space for images) */
}

#content #frame img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

So what I'm essentially doing is creating a window within a window, and then scrolling within that window, which is what leads to the [problem](http://micho.biz/mac-osx-lion-horizontal-scroll-event/) in Safari that I referred to above. Apart from that, this works exactly the way I want in Chrome and Safari. In Firefox and Opera, the images do not scale to the height of the window.

To see the site for yourself, go here: http://peter-block.com/preface/. The password is "letitrain".

What I am thinking is doing away with the "window within a window" all together would be best (simple and fixes the Safari problem), but I can't seem to find a solution that works the way I want across all browsers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this like...inception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working fiddle**, updated based on new input: **http://jsfiddle.net/XkrQg/5/**

Add `height: 100%;` to `#content #frame`

```
#content #frame {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The JS part:

Add this to the beginning of loadImages()

```
var frameWidth = 0;
```

And add this to loadImage()

```
    img.onload = function () {
        frameWidth += img.width + 5; //5 is for margin-right:5px; on img in css
        $('#frame').css('width', frameWidth);
    }
```

The solution calculates the width of `#frame` dynamically as the images are being loaded.

Add this to re-calculate the new width when the window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var frameNewWidth = 0;
    $('#frame img').each(function () {
        frameNewWidth += $(this).width() + 5;
    });
    $('#frame').css('width', frameNewWidth);
})
    .resize();
```

You can hide the vertical scroll-bar during the image loading by `overflow-x:hidden;` if you want.

Comment: The problem here is that this fixes the width to be 80000px. By not specifying the height, it renders the frame only as wide as it needs to be to fit images. Is there another way to ensure that the frame is only as wide as it needs to be?

Comment: The width wasn't part of the question. Since adding/removing elements might be needed it will be easier to provide a proper answer if you could create a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Nice... I hadn't thought of this. It's close, but not quite right. Calculating the frame width based on the image width doesn't work because the image width depends on the height of the window. This looks like it's using the native width of the images, which is much larger than what is usually displayed. Is there a way to use the rendered width of the images, as opposed to the native width? Thanks a ton for your help with this.

Comment: I updated the fiddle for you, now it takes into account the loaded and resized images.

Comment: One last question — would there be a way to have the frame width automatically adjust when the browser window is resized?

Comment: Outstanding. This has been incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cool design! What happens if you set #content `top` and `bottom` to 0. Then, `position: absolute` #frame and give it the `top: 68px;` and `bottom: 42px;` treatment. Is that the correct effect?

Comment: This is close, but has the same problem as Arbel's suggestion — that it fixes the width of the #frame at 80000px, instead of the frame only being as wide as it needs to be to fit the images.

Answer (score 1):

```
#content #frame img {

    max-height: 100%;  // for IE

}
```

- I agree with Arbel, you have to stretch height of #content #frame and I'd rather add some clearfix for #content #frame